# How to use Parcelable for a class which has multiple constructors?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Well, i was trying to pass arraylist of objects from one activity to another. I have 2 constructors in the class Student.
If, i use, Serializable than the code is like below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Student implements Serializable
{
private int studentdID;
private String studentName;
private String studentDept;

  public Student(){}

  public Student(String name, String dpt)
{ this.studentName = name;
  this.studentDept = dpt;}

  public Student(int id, String name, String dpt)
{ this.studentdID = id;
  this.studentName = name;
  this.studentDept = dpt; }

  public int getstudentdID() { return studentdID;   }
  public void setstudentdID(int studentdID) {this.studentdID = studentdID;}

  public String getstudentName() { return studentName;}
  public void setstudentName(String studentName) {this.studentName = studentName;}

  public String getstudentDept() {  return studentDept; }
  public void setstudentDept(String studentDept) { this.studentDept = studentDept;}
}
```

But the problem i am facing is that how am i going to do this with parcelable? How am i going to set the values of the variables in class-like i did with Serializable? I mean separately using 2 constructors-one without ID another without the ID?

Comment: Attack of the underscore. Why exactly are you using so many? Method names could just be camelCase and I think it'd improve readability...

Comment: edited :-) But how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Did you read how Parcelable works?

You need only one constrcutor for parcelable to read what you pass to it, and `Parcelable` interface will add a method `writeToParcel` where **you** put the data to save.

It's not an automatic process like `Serializable`, everything is up to you.

The constructor which `Parcelable` will use will accept only one argument `Parcel` where you will find some methods like `read*(KEY)` to read back values.

And in `writeToParcel` you will write in the `Parcel` (the argument of the method) the values you want pass to pass with `write*(KEY, VALUE)`.

`Parcelable` don't care about your constructors or fields.

P.S You will need a `CREATOR` too. Read some tutorial online to know more about it if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Marco's answer explains why Parcelable doesn't automatically decide what constructor to use - it can't.

However, there is a way around this. Use `Parcel.dataAvail()`, which

> Returns the amount of data remaining to be read from the parcel. That
>   is, dataSize()-dataPosition().

For example,

```
  public Student(){}

  public Student(String name, String dpt)
  { 
    this.studentName = name;
    this.studentDept = dpt;}

  public Student(int id, String name, String dpt)
  { this.studentdID = id;
    this.studentName = name;
    this.studentDept = dpt; 
  }

  public Student(Parcel in) {

     name = in.readString();
     dpt = in.readString();

     if(in.dataAvail() > 0) // is there data left to read?
          id = in.readInt();
  }
```

^ The above constructor will allow for the necessary variables to be instantiated correctly. Also, you define `writeToParcel()` something like:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out) {
    out.writeString(name);
    out.writeString(dpt);

    //0 is the default value of id if you didn't initialize it like 
   // in the first constructor. If it isn't 0, that means it was initialized.
    if(id != 0)
         out.writeInt(id);
}
```

Of course, you'll need to define your `CREATOR` like so:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {
   public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
       return new Student(in); 
   }

   public Student[] newArray(int size) {
       return new Student[size];
   }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

@u3l solution is not required..how many constructors are there it doesn't matter.
simple it works go as normal implementation.
I mean no special care is required when multiple constructors present in parcelable.

Comment: this is a comment for an answer that added by @u3l